# CreateFile fails unless I disable/enable my device

Tags: winapi, driver, wdk, internals, windows-kernel

**Updated (at bottom)**

I have a UMDF video driver based upon the IddCx sample. I have a command-line test (running 'As Administrator') that calls `CreateFile` on a video adapter device instance to get a handle to it for IOCTL purposes. The test fails on the **`CreateFile`** call with **Access Denied**

I discovered that if I simply disable and re-enable the adapter in Device Manager, and then re-run the same test, it succeeds. The test will continue to succeed until I restart Windows, or uninstall/reinstall the device.

The test's `CreateFile` call itself doesn't trigger any calls to my driver (more on that below), so I can't easily debug it from the bottom up.

Toggling the adapter device's *enabled* state changes *SOMETHING* such that the exact same `CreateFile` call succeeds. I decided to trace the `CreateFile` call until it fails... here's what I've found:

```
--- User Mode ---
mytest!CreateFile
ntdll!NtCreateFile
--- Kernel Mode ---
nt!IopCreateFile
nt!ObOpenObjectByNameEx
nt!ObpLookupObjectName
nt!IopParseDevice
nt!SeAccessCheck [returns Access Denied]
```

`nt!IopParseDevice` calls `nt!SeAccessCheck`, and when that returns `FALSE`, `nt!IopParseDevice` sets last error to *Access Denied* and returns failure.

Now, **here's the interesting part** (that I need help with):

The parameters passed into `nt!SeAccessCheck` are slightly *different*, depending upon whether I run my test *before* or *after* I disable+enable my device. Notably, the provided SecurityDescriptor parameter's `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_CONTROL` member changes:

```
(after Windows restart or adding new adapter device)
0x9814 (SE_SELF_RELATIVE | SE_SACL_PRESENT | SE_DACL_PRESENT | SE_DACL_PROTECTED | SE_SACL_AUTO_INHERITED)

(after disable/enable adapter)
0x8014 (SE_SELF_RELATIVE | SE_SACL_PRESENT | SE_DACL_PRESENT)
```

I don't know enough about Windows security to understand what these two flags signify in the larger context. Can anyone shed light on what might be going on?

---

**Update #1:**

I've found that this behavior happens with the Windows-driver-samples `video\IndirectDisplay` example project. The *only* change was to add a call to `WdfDeviceCreateDeviceInterface` between WdfDeviceCreate and IddCxDeviceInitialize, and to add a do-nothing EvtIddCxDeviceIoControl callback (just calls WdfRequestComplete with `STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST`). So, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with my particular driver (unless it's something I'm *failing* to do...)

**Update #2:**

This gets curiouser and curiouser...

It turns out that every time I cycle through disbling and then re-enabling the driver, the security descriptor that gets used is ***toggled*** (between the above two options).

Comment: Another interesting tidbit. If I sit at a breakpoint for too long in the debugger, the watchdog will assert and mark the device as non-functional (yellow triangle with exclamation point). This is expected behavior. However, when I enable it (to reset it back to working state), the test above fails; going to non-functional and then to enabled doesn't have the same effect as disabling and re-enabling. Only when I then disable/enable _again_ does the test succeed. Maybe that can provide a clue as to what's causing this...

Comment: 1) I'm not familiar with UMDF drivers (I'm more into WDM ones) and can't say what's exactly happening with your DACL (it seems that `SE_DACL_PROTECTED` is causing your problem). Have you tried to specify a SDDL string in your [`AddReg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-addreg-directive) section? (that would be [here in the sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/video/IndirectDisplay/IddSampleDriver/IddSampleDriver.inf#L39)).

Comment: 2) For more info see also [Controlling Device Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/controlling-device-access#specifying-device-security-in-an-inf-file). Be wary that the `P` in SDDL refers to `SE_DACL_PROTECTED `. Starts with a permissive SDDL string and try to built upon it.

Comment: @Neitsa - Reading up on ACLs, access tokens, privileges, security descriptors and SIDs. Will try specifying an SDDL string this weekend. Thanks.

Comment: @ScottSmith I also hit this issue, have you found a solution? Thanks.

Comment: @ravin.wang - the solution for me was to add SDDL to the .INF for the driver under **[AddReg]**, e.g.: `HKR,, Security, , "D:P(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GRGWGX;;;BA)(A;;GRGWGX;;;WD)(A;;GRGWGX;;;RC)"`

Comment: May I ask which tool you have used to trace `CreateFile` call?

Comment: @lstipakov - I can't recall for certain, but it was probably Visual Studio 2019, though it might have been WinDbg.